# Provoking an error in stdin().read_line()

Tags: rust

Consider the following short program:

```
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    loop {
        let mut command = prompt();
        println!("--> {}", command);
    }
}

fn prompt() -> String {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    print!("++> ");
    let _ = stdout().flush();
    stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).expect("Error retrieving input.");
    buffer.clone()
}
```

The result is a pretty clear looping input program - it presents a prompt, the user can type whatever and it's echoed back. What I want to know is how would I provoke the `expect()` clause to be fired? I understand that `read_line()` returns a `Result` and that `expect()` unpacks it if it is `Ok`, but I'm not sure how to practically (and manually or in a test case) force an error here to get the `panic()` result from `expect()`. I've tried a lot of different character inputs and keyboard combos but haven't found one that doesn't just quit the program or that it handles cleanly.

Comment: Might have to use a different program that wraps it and explicitely puts the stdin in an error state. I mean, it's a good thing that you didn't get the operating system to produce an error :)

Comment: It *is* good, I agree! I had not really thought about wrapping it in another program - I'll look into that!

Comment: For example `python`'s `subprocess`, for quick testing. I'm not entirely sure what causes an error in stdin, though, to be honest. I'd expect just closing stdin to be graceful, so I really have no idea.

Comment: See [the Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) for details: one example of a failure would be invalid UTF-8, as Rust strings are guaranteed to be valid UTF-8.